# How to combine radio button with a select box using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I need to combine radio buttons and a select box together.Is there any inbuilt framework to do that?. I tried a code, but its not a apt way to code. Below I'm giving the output of the code portion

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbMSN.png)

Here, Class and lab are the radio buttons,which are attached with a select box.But my code has errors. Below I'm giving the code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-cyan btn-rounded form-check-label">
<label class="btn btn-cyan btn-rounded form-check-label" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Class
</label>

<label class="btn btn-cyan btn-rounded form-check-label" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Lab
</label>
    <select class="form-check-input" autocomplete="off"> <option>HELLO</option><option>HELLO</option><option>HELLO</option></select>
</label>
 </div>
```

Here, select is became a button, because I used the class btn.Please help me to fix the code. Is their any alternative stuff already exists(Combined radio button and select box)

Comment: Want you want to achieve is not pretty clear to me. Kindly sent a sample picture of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Are you expecting the values in the dropdown to change based on the radio button selected (e.g. is `Hello` only an option for `Class` or `Lab`)?

Comment: @Stevangelista My concept is pretty simple. I have two radio buttons named class and lab.If I click class, then select box has to show respective class names and vice versa.Its simple. But here my problem is I want to make radio btn as well as select box together group as like in the image in the question. I need help in design part.

Comment: @FridayAmeh I attached a image in my question. I want help in design part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following snippet. Once you clicked on a value it will take refer the list in the javascript and post it to select options. These values are changing according to the each radio button.

You can identify by capital and simple words and how it changes on radio button click.

Cheers

```js
var listA = [{
  name: 'hello',
  value: 'hello'
}, {
  name: 'hi',
  value: 'hi'
}, {
  name: 'test',
  value: 'test'
}];

var listB = [{
  name: 'HELLO',
  value: 'HELLO'
}, {
  name: 'HI',
  value: 'HI'
}, {
  name: 'TEST',
  value: 'TEST'
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='chk']").on('change', function() {

    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'hello') {
      $('#describe').empty()
      $.each(listA, function(index, value) {
        $('#describe').append('<option value="' + value.value + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
      });
    } else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'HELLO') {
      $('#describe').empty()
      $.each(listB, function(index, value) {
        $('#describe').append('<option value="' + value.value + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
      });
    } else {

    }

  });
});
```

```css
  .radioBtn {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;

}

.radioBtn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
 
}

#describe{
  margin-left:10px
}

.lbl{
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
  background-color:#ccc;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="btn btn-cyan btn-rounded form-check-label" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
     <input type="radio" id="class" class="radioBtn" name="chk" value="hello"><label class="lbl"> Class</label>
</label>

  <label class="btn btn-cyan btn-rounded form-check-label" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
      <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" id="Club" name="chk" value="HELLO" ><label class="lbl"> Lab </label>
</label>

  <select id="describe" class="form-check-input" autocomplete="off"> 
      <option name="name" value="1">a</option>
      <option name="name" value="2">b</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Actually my problem is with the design of that. Can u connect with teamviewer?. I will explain my problem

Comment: so the radio button functions are working right? so you need a design like in the image?

Comment: Yes. Radio buttons working fine. Just now I made design somewhat ok

Comment: give me 10 minutes i can help with the design on the output picture

Comment: great. please do upvote @Sidharth you have above 15 points to upvote :)